# How to break a loop with an input?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, so please bear with me.  I'm trying to write a program involving a function that takes a number K as an input, reads K names one at a time, stores them into a list, and then prints them.

Not sure whether or not I should use a "for" or "while" loop, so I'm trying with "while" loop first.

```
k = input ("How many names?\n")

def names():
    lst = []
    while True:
        name = input("Enter name:")
        if = int(k)
            break
    return lst
names()
```

What I'm hoping to see is a list of names, and that list would be cut off after K number of names.

I've been receiving this error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-24a26badc1b5>", line 7
    if = int(k)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing the ```if name == int(k)``` I think.

Comment: Also a for would definitely be what you're looking for and right now you're loop doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @lc74 I doubt it, since that would compare a string to an int.

Comment: What were you trying to express with `if = int(k)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `while` and `for` loops is thus:

- If you want to do something a specific number of times, or once for every element in some collection, use a `for` loop.
- If you want to do something an indefinite number of times, until a certain condition is met, use a `while` loop.

The way to implement what you want using a `for` loop is this:

```
k = input("How many names?\n")

def names():
    lst = []
    for i in range(int(k)):  # creates a list `[0, 1, 2, ..., k-1]` and iterates through it, for `k` total iterations
        name = input("Enter name:")
        lst.append(name)
    return lst
names()
```

Now, you *could* do this using a `while` loop - by setting a variable like `x=0` beforehand, and increasing it by one for every iteration until `x == k`, but that's more verbose and harder to see at a glance than a `for` loop is.

Comment: Note in python3 `range` does not actually create a list. It behaves like `xrange` in python2 i.e. it's lazily evaluated and essentially a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Equality comparisons in Python are done with a

```
==
```

You also need some sort of thing to compare int(k) to. If you're trying to count loops you could do something like

```
x = 0
while True:
    name = input("Enter name:")
    lst.append(name)
    x+= 1
    if x== int(k)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

**[@Green Cloak Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648811/green-cloak-guy)** explained very well why a for loop would be appropriate for your task. However if you do want to use a while loop you could do something like this:

```
def get_names(num_names):
  names = []
  i = 1
  while i <= num_names: # equivalent to `for i in range(1, num_names + 1):`
    current_name = input(f"Please enter name {i}: ")
    names.append(current_name)
    i += 1
  return names


def main():
  num_names = int(input("How many names are to be entered? "))
  names = get_names(num_names)
  print(f"The names are: {names}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
How many names are to be entered? 3
Please enter name 1: Adam
Please enter name 2: Bob
Please enter name 3: Charlie
The names are: ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what a `for` loop is for - looping "for" a certain number of times. A `while` loop is for indefinite loops where you keep looping until something is no longer true.

Still, it might be instructive to see both, so you can better understand the difference. Here's the `for` loop. It will loop `k` times. See the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) for more details.

```
k = int(input ("How many names?\n"))

def names():
    lst = []
    for i in range(k):
        name = input("Enter name:")
        lst.append(name) # I'm assuming you want to add each name to the end of lst
    return lst
names()
```

And here's the same thing as a `while` loop. The loop continues until the loop condition is not true, so you just need to come up with a conditional that is true for the first `k` loops, and not thereafter. This will do:

```
k = int(input ("How many names?\n"))

def names():
    lst = []
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        name = input("Enter name:")
        lst.append(name) # I'm assuming you want to add each name to the end of lst
        i += 1
    return lst
names()
```

Notice how in a `while` loop you have to initialise and increment the iterator (`i`) yourself, which is why a `for` loop is more suitable.

Finally, notice how neither example uses `break`. `break` is a fine way to end a loop, but if it's not necessary then you're better off not using it - generally it is only used to end a loop by exception (that is, for some reason that is not the main loop conditional). Using it for normal loop endings leads to less logical code that is harder to follow.